# Firebase emulators blocking firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

So in my web app, I am calling an https callable cloud function like so

```
const createStripeCheckout = functions.httpsCallable('createStripeCheckout')
//Call function
```

And up until I started using the firebase emulator, everything was fine. It was making a request to the https endpoint, and the checkout was made successfully. But after I used functions in the emulator, it makes a request to the local dev server (localhost:5000/firebase-project/name) instead of the correct https endpoint hosted by firebase (firebase/name) and the function can't work unless I start the emulator, and will only work on my computer. I don't recall changing any settings.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, in my code there was a line that read:

```
functions.useEmulators("localhost", 5001)
```

I guess that directed all functions to that adress